# The example related to separate sets in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I have another question. I am studying separate sets ın $\Bbb R^n$ and I have understand some theorems related to separate sets. And then, I see an example related to it. But I dont understand. I posted the example and its figure. I underlined the example with blue pencil. Please again explain me more clear. Thank you for help:)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the point $(0,0)$ is not contained in the set, thus you have a separation given, for example, by

$$U = \{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x_1<0\},\ V = U = \{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x_1>0\}$$

Also, to answer to the question at the end of the underlined part, a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is connected if, and only if it is an interval.